# How to hook async Backbone event to display of HTML

Tags: backbone.js

What I am trying to do is make a call to the database and then display the result in some HTML.  I have everything working (the data comes back from the database just fine), except I can't figure out to display the data.

I know that `fetch()` is async, but I'm not sure how to wire it into my collection view.  Here is my Backbone:

```
    (function() {
        window.App = {
            Models: {},
            Collections: {},
            Views: {},
            Router: {}
        };

        window.template = function(id) {
            return _.template( $('#' + id).html() );
        };

        App.Models.Main = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults : {
                FName: ''
            }
        });

        App.Collections.Mains = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: App.Models.Main,
            initialize: function(mains) {
                this.fetch({success: function(main) {
                    $('#web-leads').html(main);
                }});
            },
            url: '../leads/main_contact'
        });

        App.Views.Mains = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'ul',
            render: function() {
                var ul = this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
                return ul;
            },
            addOne: function(main) {
                var mainC = new App.Views.Main({ model: main});
                this.$el.append(mainC.render().el);
                return this;
            }
        });

        App.Views.Main = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'li',
            template: template('mainContactTemplate'),
            render: function () {
                this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }

        });

        main = new App.Views.Main();
        mains = new App.Collections.Mains(main);

    })();
```

What I need to be able to is call `$('#web-leads').html()` with the value returned from `mains`.  How do I do that?

Comment: Your view should be listening for `"reset"` events from the collection (that's what a `fetch` will trigger), then the view deals with all the HTML stuff. A collection shouldn't be messing around with the DOM at all.

Comment: OK.  Where do I listen for listen for reset?

Comment: Whatever view is displaying the collection should `this.collection.on('reset', ...)`. I have to run or I'd give you a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern for this sort of thing in Backbone is:

1. create a model or collection
2. pass that model/colleciton to a view
3. that view registers an event handler on the model/collection
4. the model/collection triggers an AJAX request (probably in response to a `fetch` call)
5. the view's event handler is triggered
6. the view's event handler updates the page

So, as mu is too short suggested, your best bet is to follow this pattern and have your view bind a handler to your collection's `reset` event.

It's worth mentioning however that `reset` won't always be the event you want to bind.  For instance, you might not want to respond an AJAX request unless it changed attribute 'X' of the model.  In that case you could instead bind to `change:X`, and then your handler would only be triggered if the AJAX response changed X.

To see all your possible options, see:

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-catalog

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track just needed to have the view listening to the Collection rather than the collection listening to the view.

The below is your code with the slight modification of who listens to who.

Why?  Ideally we want the Collections to know nothing of the Views.

```
(function() {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Router: {}
    };

    window.template = function(id) {
        return _.template( $('#' + id).html() );
    };

    App.Models.Main = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            FName: ''
        }
    });

    App.Collections.Mains = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.Models.Main,

        url: '../leads/main_contact'
    });

    App.Views.Mains = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',
        initialize : function(){
          this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
        },
        render: function() {
            var ul = this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
            return ul;
        },
        addOne: function(main) {
            var mainC = new App.Views.Main({ model: main});
            this.$el.append(mainC.render().el);
            return this;
        }
    });

    App.Views.Main = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        template: template('mainContactTemplate'),
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }

    });

    mains = new App.Collections.Mains();
    main = new App.Views.Main( {'collection' : mains} );
    mains.fetch(); 

})();
```

Comment: Your answer might be good but without explanations, it really looks like a wall of code

Comment: Why did you take out `fetch()`?  It's not going to work without that.  Even with that, I don't think it works.

Comment: @nikoshr I was in a bit of a rush so just thought the code would at least get the question pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @sehummel I just forgot the .fetch() call.