# Binding data to the DOM in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

Here's my Backbone.js:

```
(function() {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Router: {}
    };

    window.template = function(id) {
        return _.template( $('#' + id).html() );
    };

    var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

    App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '' : 'index',
            '*other' : 'other'
        },
        index: function() {

        },
        other: function() {

        }
    });


    App.Models.Main = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            FName: ''
        }
    });

    App.Collections.Mains = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: App.Models.Main,
        initialize: function() {
            this.fetch({
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.models);
                }
            });
        },
        url: '../leads/main_contact'
    });

    App.Views.Mains = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ul',
        initialize: function() {
            this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
            console.log(this.collection);
        },
        render: function() {
            return this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);
        },
        addOne: function(main) {
            var mainC = new App.Views.Main({ model: main});
            this.$el.append(mainC.render().el);
            return this;
        }
    });

    App.Views.Main = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'li',
        template: template('mainContactTemplate'),
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }

    });

    mains = new App.Collections.Mains();
    main = new App.Views.Main({ collection: mains});

    new App.Router;
    Backbone.history.start();
})();
```

What I want to do is have the data returned in the `ul` to be bound to a DOM element called `$('#web-leads')`.  How do I do that, given this code?  Incidentally, I've already posted about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162995/how-to-hook-async-backbone-event-to-display-of-html) and tried to follow the first answer and the second answer combined.  But I still don't get HTML and data bound to the DOM.  The data is returning from the server correctly in my collection, so I know that's not the problem.  Don't worry about the router stuff.  That's for later.

Comment: You have two `App.Views.Main`s; the first one is completely meaningless, as it just gets overwritten by the second one.

Comment: One is `App.Views.Main` and is the view for the li.  The other is `App.Views.Mains` and is the view for the collection.

Comment: Whoops, I failed at reading :-)

Comment: No problem.  It happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally in Backbone you don't put data on DOM elements: you put it in views that wrap that DOM element.

That being said, if you really want to store data on the element, jQuery has a function for that:

```
$('#web-leads').data('someKey', 'yourData');
```

Then you can retrieve that data with:

```
$('#web-leads').data('someKey');
```

*** EDIT ***

In a comments discussion with the OP it became apparent that the real goal was simply to append a view's element to an element on the page.  If the element being appended to is `#web-leads`, then this can be accomplished with:

```
$('#web-leads').append(theView.render().el);
```

Comment: My data is my HTML.  How do I get my HTML to the DOM element?

Comment: I'm trying to bind my data to an HTML template and then return that to the DOM.

Comment: I'm still kinda confused about what you are trying to achieve.  When you say that do you mean this line `this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));`?  Because that is "binding data" (this.model) to a template and then putting it (via `.html()`) in to the DOM.

Comment: Then why isn't it displaying on the page?

Comment: I thought I needed to tell BB where in the DOM to put it, other than in the `ul li`.

Comment: The `ul li` is nowhere in the DOM I have.  I'm trying to add it to `$('#web-leads')`.

Comment: Ohhhh ... ok then your question has nothing to do with data at all, you're just trying to figure out how to add an element to the DOM (you might want to consider editing your original question to clarify).  In that case, it's easy: `$('#web-leads').append(whateverView.render().el);`.

Comment: Well, it really depends on when you want it to happen.  If web-leads has a view, then that view's render  method is one obvious place.  If not, then in the render (or initialize if you prefer) of whatever view is the "parent".

Comment: In general in Backbone if you have element C inside of B, inside of A, then A's render view appends B's view, and B's render appends C's view.  As for the top-level view (A in this case), generally it is appended in your main js file, or on a script on the HTML page, or somewhere like that.

Comment: You're quite welcome; I'll update my answer based on our comment discussion.

Comment: Thanks, so much, machineghost!

Comment: That breaks encapsulation.  Getting the 'el' off of the view is bad practice in my opinion.