# replace of undefined in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I just want to bind the model data to the DOM. But so far I got error of replace of undefined. Something is wrong.

This is my script.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            name:"",
            age:20,
            job:'jobless'
        }
    });

    var person1 = new Person({
        name:"Sony",
        age: 30,
        job: "Teacher"
    });

    var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            tagName:'li';
            var html_content = this.model.get('name') + ', ' + this.model.get('age') + 
            ' (' + this.model.get('job') + ')';
            var template = _.template($('#container_template').html(this),{})
            this.$el.html(template);
        }
    });

    var person_view = new PersonView({model:person1});


</script>
```

and I have a template like this in my bodo tag

```
<script type="text/template" id="container_template">

        </script>
```

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle

Comment: this question is very similar to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165257/binding-data-to-the-dom-in-backbone check it

Comment: @YolloPain I got a working version but it use template, I want to dive in in depth how backbone work.

Comment: You're using an old tutorial, `_.template(tmpl, data)` no longer works as of Underscore 1.7.0, now you need to do it in two steps so `t = _.template(tmpl); h = t(data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without template

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            name:"",
            age:20,
            job:'jobless'
        }
    });

    var person1 = new Person({
        name:"Sony",
        age: 30,
        job: "Teacher"
    });

    var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName:'ul',
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){

            var entry = document.createElement('li');
            firstname=this.model.get('name');
            entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(firstname));
            this.$el.html(entry);
            return this;
        }
    });

    var person_view = new PersonView({model:person1});
$("body").html(person_view.el);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this make sense, thanks. but it's much easier to do it with this.$el like this https://jsfiddle.net/b01vtfnh/

Comment: but you wanted list iteam so i did like this

Answer (score 0):

with template

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/template" id="container_template">
<li><%=name%></li>
<li><%=age%></li>
<li><%=job%></li> 

        </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            name:"",
            age:20,
            job:'jobless'
        }
    });

    var person1 = new Person({
        name:"Sony",
        age: 30,
        job: "Teacher"
    });

    var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName:'ul',
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            var template = _.template($('#container_template').html());
            var hi= template(this.model.toJSON());
            this.$el.html(hi);
            return this;
        }
    });

    var person_view = new PersonView({model:person1});
$("body").html(person_view.el);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what if I don't want to use template?